# How do 100mA ELCBs provide human protection?

Tags: grounding, rcd, electrocution

Usually we use 30mA rated ELCBs in our homes. This is for our own protection against leakage current. But in instances where you have a 100mA or 250mA 3 pole ELCB used in industry, an earth leakage of about 60mA would shock you before the ELCB trips. So how are humans protected in this case?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Is an "ELCB" the same as a GFCI or RCD?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, earth-leakage circuit breaker. Not sure where that particular term is used though, it's not one you see often.

Comment: Some information from Schneider-Electric [Link](https://www.schneider-electric.com/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/328000/FA328983/en_US/earth%20leakage%20protection%20selection.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

ELCB were not initially quite same than a RCD, but now the terms are used interchangeably. ELCB is a device to detect leakage in a high impedance ground system by measuring ground voltage, so it does not detect current difference between live and neutral which is how the RCD works.

The point of a 100mA or 250mA protection device is not so much to protect humans touching mains electricity directly, but to protect devices and buildings from fires caused by improperly installed or damaged wiring so that they do not cause fires.

Also 250mA leakage to ground within a device like a motor may not pose a direct hazard to humans at all, unless the ground wiring is faulty and has too much resistance so that the 250mA causes a dangerous voltage to grounded metal casing, when compared to other grounded devices.

Answer (score 1):

EU has higher leakage ratings to prevent nuisance trips from high humidity, dust, but using a safe limit that prevents injury to humans, but it might scare you with a shock.

<=6mA protect humans from major sensation
<=30mA safe limit to prevent harm
<= 100mA safe limit to protect some equipment but not cause heart attack
<=1A to prevent fires for say swimming pool equipment

While North American standards for GFCI leakage trip <5mA are much lower based on a lower sensation of ground faults above the threshold of sensing through the body and also at 1/2 the voltage = 120V.  All earth grounded appliances with line filters to gnd are factory tested to not exceed 2.5mA but are tested with ~ 1mA threshold by design usually depending on line noise filter suppression. Every unit must be safety to not exceed these limits.

HOWEVER, This can cause more nuisance trips such as kettle steam and smoke from toaster with leakage thru the air to stove ground tripping kitchen GFCI.  Or Shower in the bathroom with dust in the air leaking current to plumbing fixture earth grounds but this is not very common but can occur.

More details and history:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device
https://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/differences-between-gfci-idci-and-gfpe
 https://www.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ul_GroundFaultProtectiveDevices.pdf
http://osha.in/444-2/    (US Safety site)

**Short Answer:** EU std is higher to prevent death and false-positive trips while N Amer. (US,CAN etc) std is more sensitive and may have more false trips.

The choice is yours depending on installation and Class of equipment.